# Why my USB mouse gets suspended after 3 seconds of inactivity?

Tags: linux, usb, mouse, suspend

Mouse's bottom LED goes off after 3 seconds after connection and cursor movements and wheel stops. Pressing any button, reconnecting or resetting USB device resumes it for another 3 seconds (when resumed by pressing button, this event does no go to X).

This happens when using any of USB ports. This mouse works well with other computer with Linux. It was working well before.

Why can it happen? How to fix it?

**Update**: It happens only if laptop is on battery.

**Answer**: this is caused by powersaving done by laptop-mode-tools. To temporary turn off powersaving one can use

```
for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/control; do echo on > $i; done
```

Comment: This only happens on linux, or other operation systems?

Comment: I have just observed it. May be reboot will fix it, but I want to know why this can happen.

Comment: My crappy no name wireless mouse does this. It doesn't matter if my computer is plugged in or on battery. To make matters worse, no amount of activity will "unsuspend" the mouse once it gets stuck, forcing me to remove and reinsert the batteries every 3-5 seconds. Useless piece of s**t.

Comment: @Vi.: I propose changing the accepted answer to the one of OscarGarcia, because his is the most accurate, actually answers both your questions, and doesn't have any side-effects like disabling USB autosuspend at all...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a very old question, related with laptop-mode, but I'll post my solution:

In Ubuntu 14.04 I edited `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf` and change this lines to blacklist `usbhid`:

```
# The list of USB driver types that should not use autosuspend.  The driver
# type is given by "DRIVER=..." in a USB device's uevent file.
# Example: AUTOSUSPEND_USBID_BLACKLIST="usbhid usb-storage"
## Old value: AUTOSUSPEND_USBTYPE_BLACKLIST=""
AUTOSUSPEND_USBTYPE_BLACKLIST="usbhid"
```

In Ubuntu 12.04 I must to edit `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/runtime-pm.conf` and change this lines to blacklist `usbhid`:

```
# The list of device driver types that should use autosuspend.  The driver
# type is given by "DRIVER=..." in a device's uevent file.
# Example: AUTOSUSPEND_DEVTYPE_WHITELIST="usbhid usb-storage"
## Old value: AUTOSUSPEND_RUNTIME_DEVTYPE_WHITELIST=""
AUTOSUSPEND_RUNTIME_DEVTYPE_WHITELIST="usbhid"
```

You can also blacklist `usb-storage`! and you can also blacklist device by ID (`AUTOSUSPEND_RUNTIME_DEVID_WHITELIST` in Ubuntu 12.04 or `AUTOSUSPEND_USBID_BLACKLIST` in Ubuntu 14.04).

Then you'll need to restart laptop mode for the changes to take effect:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/laptop-mode restart
```

And then replug mouse. The mouse will not suspend again.

This works for me at work (ubuntu 12.04) and home (ubuntu 14.04).

Hope It helps :)

Comment: This answer solved my problem in Debian. I blacklisted `usbhid` and `psmouse` and after restarting `laptop-mode` service, and replug my mouse, the issue is solved

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer, since it only blacklists autosuspend of HID devices, but leaves you the possibility to autosuspend all other devices.

Comment: Because of that I suggest `AUTOSUSPEND_USBID_BLACKLIST` too.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 14.04, lenovo thinkpad :(

Comment: @Thomas which of the solutions does not work for you? Could you share the lsusb id or the module, mouse type, ect? If it is using an wireless adaptor, maybe it is necessary to blacklist it too! Edit: do you have `laptop-tools` installed?

Answer (score 12):

I have the perfect solution!

If

```
for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/control; do echo on > $i; done
```

works for you, but only once, edit `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf` to replace :

```
CONTROL_USB_AUTOSUSPEND="auto"
```

by

```
CONTROL_USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0
```

It works for me.

Comment: Man, you really said something that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know that I had the 'laptop-mode-tools' package installed.. It may also explain other problems with the cpu scalling indicator I had.

Comment: only the first command (for ...) did work. I tried everything even stopping laptop-mode service and it didn't change. Thanks

Comment: The file `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf` doesn't exist for me. Should I create it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behaviour of all mouses after they are getting wireless, to save battery. you can adjust it if it has a 3rd party software coming within the box.

Comment: He doesn't says if it's a wireless mouse.

Comment: This is wired USB mouse.

Comment: Ok. I just looked my wired usb mouse and also it is getting inactive after 5 seconds, and this is also for energy saving, because you may use it with a laptop which battery time matters. And isn't it a good feature?

Comment: The LED is not dimmed, but is off at all, preventing the normal use of mouse (need to click every time before moving).

Comment: Battery saving? Probably, because of turning the netbook to AC prevents turning off mouse. How to [temporarily] disable such energy saving?

Comment: firstly try "sudo pm-powersave false" if not work search for "laptop-mode-tools"

Comment: "pm-powersave false" does nothing, but disabling laptop-mode-tools works.

Comment: Please comment on the answer above, this one is completely wrong and misleading.